# Как подписаться на пользователя instagram?

Tags: php, instagram

Как подписаться на пользователя instagram в обход официльного API, используя свой логин и пароль ?

Comment: тоже интересен вопрос, удалось ли воспроизвести? отправляю тот же post запрос как наснифирил, но в друзья не добавляется.

Answer (score 1):

Открой в `Chrome` режим разработки, нажми на кнопку <kbd>Подписаться</kbd> и посмотри запросы, которые уходят; повтори запросы `Curl`'ом.

Comment: Не могли бы привести пример кода на php или js?
вот запрос https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/user_id/follow/

Comment: это и так понятно, проблема что тот же самый пост запрос почему то не работает. по видимому есть еще какая то фишка.